# Will the Blend 4 will work with the Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

Does the ultimate version of the Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 contains windows phone SDK and with Expression Blend 4?
I cannot find info about that even on Microsoft site.

Comment: Which version of the Phone SDK are you targeting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 and Expression Blend 4 are companion applications, sharing the same SLN and .csproj, vbproj files.  Visual Studio 2012 also has a companion version of Blend (Blend for MS Visual Studio 2012).

None of the above IDEs are ready for Phone development.  You need to install the SDK before they can create phone projects.  During the install process, the SDK adds the appropriate templates to your computer.

If you have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate it has a placeholder for phone projects.  See the screenshot below.

[image: screen shot]

The new version of Blend(Blend for MS Visual Studio 2012) doesn't support phone projects at all.

[image: Blend Projects]

There is an [Beta version of Blend available](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2012/09/26/microsoft-moves-closer-to-a-unified-expression-blend-2012-release/), with more project types, and the release version is coming soon.  [See this post for more details.](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2012/09/26/microsoft-moves-closer-to-a-unified-expression-blend-2012-release/)

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate version of Visual Studio 2012 contains Blend for Visual Studio 2012 (effectively "Blend 5"). Not sure why you'd need Blend 4 at that point.

Comment: Blend 2012 is incomplete, and only supports Windows Store applications.

Comment: The more complete version of Blend is currently in "Preview" http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702